# netplan STP enabled or disabled

Tags: 20.04, netplan, network-bridge

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS and configured bridges. I am not sure if STP is enabled or disabled by default on netplan created bridges. As per netplan doc [1] its `Enabled` by default.

[1] https://netplan.io/reference

This is my netplan config and i didn't set `stp: false` option.

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/00-eno50-sriov-network-config.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno49:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      mtu: 9000
    eno50:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      mtu: 9000
      virtual-function-count: 12

  vlans:
    # br-mgmt
    eno49.51:
      id: 51
      link: eno49
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      mtu: 1500

    # br-vxlan
    eno49.29:
      id: 29
      link: eno49
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      mtu: 9000

  bridges:
    br-mgmt:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      interfaces: [ eno49.51 ]
      addresses: [ 10.74.1.12/23 ]
      gateway4: 10.74.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [ 10.30.0.8, 10.30.0.10 ]
        search: [ foo.com, bar.com ]

    br-vxlan:
      interfaces: [ eno49.29 ]
      addresses: [ 172.29.11.12/21 ]
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no

    br-vlan:
      interfaces: [ eno49 ]
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
```

When i check stp status using brctl, it's saying STP is disabled. It contradict to Ubuntu official doc

```
$ brctl show
bridge name bridge id           STP enabled  interfaces
br-mgmt     8000.38eaa7327d40   no           eno49.51
br-vlan     8000.38eaa7327d40   no           eno49
br-vxlan    8000.38eaa7327d40   no           eno49.29
```

Answer (score 0):

If the behavior contradicts the documentation, that is a bug. Please report bugs at bugs.launchpad.net/netplan.

Comment: Already did here - https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/2007304